# audible sound in c++

Tags: c++, audio

Is there anyway to output an audible bell in c++?

Comment: You can send the bell `\a` character to standard output. Whether it produces a sound or not depends on the hardware.

Comment: `system("beep")` or `Beep` works on Windows as well.. Also depends on your hardware..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code;

```
cout<<"\a";
```

This will generate an audible bell.